# Why is my data printing in brackets

Tags: python, file, reader

Here is my code

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')

timeStart = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print 'Starting brute force attack'

try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
       print str(row)

finally:
    f.close()
```

My actual output is:
['zyzzyvas']

The file it is read in from has entries like:
zythem
zyzzyvas

I just want it to print the string not the other stuff what am I missing?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why are you using a CSV reader if you don't seem to want CSV parsing?

Comment: `row` is a list whose first element is your string. You can do `print row[0]`

Comment: take the first index then. `[][0]`

Comment: Also include the code in a `with open` block so you don't have to worry about closing a file. As soon as the code in the `with` block is executed, it closes the file. Another comment: what does `count` do?

Answer (score 0):

try using `print ( (' ').join(row))`

Comment: Can you provide a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` your row back into a string with:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
       print ' '.join(row)
```